# How to determine the correct UIScrollView zoomScale with a CATiledLayer

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, catiledlayer

I created a `UIScrollView` with a `CATiledLayer` for a 10000x8078 image.

Would I place this image in a `UIView` the `zoomScale` is always updated according to the `contentSize` (respectively the size of the image).

With `CATiledLayer` the `contentSize` now varies according to the tiles in use.

How can I now determine the correct `zoomScale` of the `UISrcollView`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has worked for me, based on the the [ZoomingPDFViewer Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html), is to keep tabs on the zoom manually the following way in the UIScrollView delegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{

    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    // set the new scale factor for the TiledPDFView
    pdfScale *=scale;
        ....
```